# sklearn pipeline model predicting same results for all input

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

In the program, I am scanning a number of brain samples taken in a time series of 40 x 64 x 64 images every 2.5 seconds. The number of 'voxels' (3D pixels) in each image is thus ~ 168,000 ish (40 * 64 * 64), each of which is a 'feature' for an image sample.

I thought of using Recursive Feature Elimination (RFE).  Then follow this up with Principle Component Analysis (PCA) because of the rediculously high n to perform dimensionality reduction.

There are 9 classes to predict. Thus a multi class classification problem. Starting with RFE:

```
estimator = SVC(kernel='linear')
rfe = RFE(estimator,n_features_to_select= 20000, step=0.05)
rfe = rfe.fit(X_train,y_train)
X_best = rfe.transform(X_train)
```

Now perform PCA :

```
X_best = scale(X_best)

def get_optimal_number_of_components():
    cov = np.dot(X_best,X_best.transpose())/float(X_best.shape[0])
    U,s,v = svd(cov)
    print 'Shape of S = ',s.shape

    S_nn = sum(s)

    for num_components in range(0,s.shape[0]):
        temp_s = s[0:num_components]
        S_ii = sum(temp_s)
        if (1 - S_ii/float(S_nn)) <= 0.01:
            return num_components

    return s.shape[0]

n_comp = get_optimal_number_of_components()
print 'optimal number of components = ', n_comp

pca = PCA(n_components = n_comp)
pca = pca.fit(X_best)
X_pca_reduced = pca.transform(X_best)
```

Train the reduced component dataset with SVM

```
svm = SVC(kernel='linear',C=1,gamma=0.0001)
svm = svm.fit(X_pca_reduced,y_train)
```

Now transform the training set to RFE-PCA reduced and make the predictions

```
X_rfe = rfe.transform(X_test)
X_pca = pca.transform(X_rfe)

predictions = svm.predict(X_pca) 

print 'predictions = ',predictions
print 'actual = ',y_test
```

But I always get the same values for prediction for every sample!

```
predictions =  [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2] #Why is it the same?!!
actual = actual =  [[0]
 [0]
 [6]
 [8]
 [4]
 [5]
 [0]
 [6]
 [2]
 [3]
 [0]
 [5]
 [6]]
```

I made sure to use linear kernel. I also considered modifying C,gamma with values like (1,0.001) (1,0.0001) (10, 0.001), (10, 0.0001) ... but I get the same output.

Is there something I'm missing here?

**EDIT 1**

I executed

```
print svm.decision_function(X_pca)
```

and the output was :

```
[[ -4.79479982e+02  -8.01563453e+02  -9.91453849e+02  -1.34641884e+02
   -1.02315530e+03  -2.88297991e+02  -8.41843812e+02   4.79807826e+02
   -3.50485820e+02  -2.31081776e+02  -1.42555136e+02  -4.79034448e+02
   -6.93029988e+01  -7.34288793e+02  -5.49271317e+01   1.98108304e+02
    4.80257991e+02   2.46835670e+02   2.90045437e+02   1.53261114e+02
    9.15742824e+02  -1.28387833e+01  -3.05045240e+02  -2.19268988e+01
   -2.24896384e+02   1.44501465e+02  -9.17438352e+01  -6.96148972e+01
   -1.15785658e+02   9.53878230e+01   1.79823987e+01   8.05242433e+01
    8.33917960e+02  -1.69686889e+01   9.85949158e+01   2.68935397e+02]
 [ -4.62804973e+02  -8.26454112e+02  -9.83214857e+02  -1.43367127e+02
   -1.03538041e+03  -2.86397664e+02  -8.47539241e+02   4.63709033e+02
   -3.52018380e+02  -2.49936725e+02  -1.43734219e+02  -4.79498907e+02
   -6.93338619e+01  -7.51141272e+02  -5.30999658e+01   1.95687050e+02
    4.69206888e+02   2.46530774e+02   2.92047409e+02   1.47934614e+02
    9.27901865e+02  -1.21801344e+01  -2.99530129e+02  -2.03238750e+01
   -2.26862390e+02   1.47692745e+02  -8.81396485e+01  -6.41692405e+01
   -1.14247569e+02   1.01567350e+02   1.87874038e+01   6.90549126e+01
    8.41984280e+02  -2.04488188e+01   1.00839951e+02   2.75459577e+02]
 [ -4.49255185e+02  -7.89243063e+02  -9.78820180e+02  -1.29050171e+02
   -1.01784356e+03  -3.23431625e+02  -7.98795796e+02   4.93058279e+02
   -3.64674793e+02  -2.46545700e+02  -1.66933546e+02  -4.84571326e+02
   -9.93316258e+01  -7.36182373e+02  -6.23110881e+01   2.08061873e+02
    4.28119725e+02   2.75927668e+02   2.36425246e+02   1.69950273e+02
    9.50488041e+02  -3.17986619e+01  -3.03656967e+02  -4.78710028e+01
   -2.20752797e+02   1.36973850e+02  -5.31583763e+01  -1.08205173e+02
   -7.94698530e+01   1.37320498e+02  -2.31183352e+01   8.41399154e+01
    8.26408412e+02   1.30471236e+01   1.48266050e+02   2.55914495e+02]
 [ -4.80424764e+02  -8.07660826e+02  -9.91911478e+02  -1.35981428e+02
   -1.02923114e+03  -2.93372818e+02  -8.47420541e+02   4.60149182e+02
   -3.48333176e+02  -2.37654055e+02  -1.39277819e+02  -4.78486235e+02
   -6.83571401e+01  -7.34632739e+02  -5.73953318e+01   1.95508198e+02
    4.80569807e+02   2.37500896e+02   2.89038289e+02   1.49855773e+02
    9.09217973e+02  -1.04236971e+01  -3.02128880e+02  -2.16485093e+01
   -2.23313869e+02   1.43686084e+02  -9.74071814e+01  -7.22417410e+01
   -1.19091495e+02   8.94390723e+01   1.97000084e+01   8.08496457e+01
    8.39105553e+02  -1.82282013e+01   9.82685256e+01   2.67791421e+02]
 [ -4.74406707e+02  -8.18308535e+02  -9.76126419e+02  -1.74849565e+02
   -1.02784293e+03  -2.96842934e+02  -8.42749406e+02   4.83769137e+02
   -3.59483221e+02  -2.24264385e+02  -1.61995143e+02  -4.78030614e+02
   -8.02309023e+01  -7.54316452e+02  -5.43436450e+01   2.05876768e+02
    4.33470519e+02   2.67598191e+02   2.75764466e+02   1.53323191e+02
    9.45967383e+02  -2.93192233e+01  -3.04615693e+02  -3.20731950e+01
   -2.42783848e+02   1.40891844e+02  -6.13739832e+01  -6.15060481e+01
   -9.51924850e+01   1.35666499e+02   2.41364468e+00   6.39635318e+01
    8.37881867e+02  -1.03313421e+01   1.19234038e+02   2.76305651e+02]
 [ -4.84321668e+02  -8.07444080e+02  -1.01507160e+03  -1.28529685e+02
   -1.05601843e+03  -2.99493242e+02  -8.41745493e+02   4.75608122e+02
   -3.37295601e+02  -2.49242183e+02  -1.30463265e+02  -4.74284269e+02
   -6.05670230e+01  -7.34447396e+02  -4.01117838e+01   1.80948824e+02
    4.80450158e+02   2.19859113e+02   2.94798893e+02   1.35958067e+02
    9.13259527e+02  -3.52105914e-01  -2.92301811e+02  -1.24432589e+01
   -2.13204265e+02   1.64167920e+02  -1.02951065e+02  -7.04800774e+01
   -1.31293866e+02   9.12032854e+01   2.67291593e+01   7.78485633e+01
    8.74745197e+02  -2.50250734e+01   9.69993408e+01   2.83018293e+02]
 [ -4.68184798e+02  -7.85221871e+02  -9.98980941e+02  -1.08799100e+02
   -1.02080996e+03  -2.87470373e+02  -8.29552725e+02   4.99360929e+02
   -3.31724034e+02  -2.56603688e+02  -1.24320652e+02  -4.60348857e+02
   -6.21852802e+01  -7.31782526e+02  -2.56669989e+01   1.74050279e+02
    4.74370392e+02   2.26812613e+02   2.78945379e+02   1.29667612e+02
    9.21512986e+02   3.74936721e+00  -2.77509203e+02  -1.34603952e+01
   -2.12032693e+02   1.72842580e+02  -9.71967056e+01  -8.19354011e+01
   -1.32985460e+02   9.55148610e+01   1.66381043e+01   5.88073445e+01
    8.62770538e+02  -2.37682031e+01   1.06714435e+02   2.94158166e+02]
 [ -4.63681347e+02  -8.22291452e+02  -9.98021515e+02  -1.54810425e+02
   -1.03372001e+03  -3.34322759e+02  -8.34407336e+02   4.71050572e+02
   -3.69327864e+02  -2.40580250e+02  -1.65003310e+02  -4.88818830e+02
   -9.73775374e+01  -7.51246204e+02  -6.69606962e+01   2.13573607e+02
    4.49817824e+02   2.79532473e+02   2.41873397e+02   1.69963589e+02
    9.53153717e+02  -2.88140674e+01  -3.13030733e+02  -4.54555034e+01
   -2.32589565e+02   1.36869994e+02  -6.33773098e+01  -1.06164181e+02
   -8.91557438e+01   1.24881490e+02  -1.94528381e+01   7.98035685e+01
    8.22835959e+02   8.75642083e+00   1.43002335e+02   2.61562868e+02]
 [ -4.77620825e+02  -8.40698094e+02  -1.01067455e+03  -1.56851274e+02
   -1.05031578e+03  -3.14666532e+02  -8.46541414e+02   4.61714738e+02
   -3.60822150e+02  -2.44485564e+02  -1.53420660e+02  -4.85710648e+02
   -7.77752216e+01  -7.55747678e+02  -5.87745617e+01   2.04601581e+02
    4.68781099e+02   2.63234873e+02   2.86306284e+02   1.58817281e+02
    9.43249321e+02  -1.87631625e+01  -3.06321663e+02  -2.78828679e+01
   -2.27554363e+02   1.46508283e+02  -7.88844807e+01  -7.41051812e+01
   -1.05094485e+02   1.12231546e+02   7.97692231e+00   7.67304852e+01
    8.43518403e+02  -1.12844915e+01   1.13370158e+02   2.70797472e+02]
 [ -4.91420429e+02  -7.90722180e+02  -1.05615447e+03  -1.20351520e+02
   -1.04098604e+03  -2.92426682e+02  -8.45105853e+02   4.78228854e+02
   -3.10412377e+02  -2.77543578e+02  -1.09733119e+02  -4.40834428e+02
   -4.35168704e+01  -7.29088994e+02  -6.64581241e+00   1.48560861e+02
    4.74565890e+02   2.07485677e+02   2.99817382e+02   1.09936148e+02
    9.03346951e+02   2.26102442e+01  -2.45854761e+02   8.31279855e+00
   -1.92441568e+02   2.03079787e+02  -1.05267244e+02  -6.41835912e+01
   -1.49582656e+02   8.73008441e+01   3.36913246e+01   5.11061286e+01
    8.79159912e+02  -3.85152954e+01   9.08938445e+01   3.04037825e+02]
 [ -4.85998114e+02  -7.83944995e+02  -9.68132304e+02  -1.54631678e+02
   -1.01186983e+03  -2.80419560e+02  -8.72211797e+02   4.97352635e+02
   -3.56256101e+02  -2.23204297e+02  -1.55355470e+02  -4.80882457e+02
   -7.86287112e+01  -7.58318471e+02  -5.10727433e+01   2.08265151e+02
    4.49457388e+02   2.65764723e+02   2.72435473e+02   1.53296624e+02
    9.44654406e+02  -2.50922419e+01  -3.17539501e+02  -3.16241295e+01
   -2.51387679e+02   1.38109115e+02  -6.97122491e+01  -6.59836763e+01
   -1.03441764e+02   1.19472073e+02   3.60256872e+00   6.22040523e+01
    8.19929661e+02  -1.26581261e+01   1.12555974e+02   2.80480600e+02]
 [ -4.70876215e+02  -7.87431621e+02  -9.96007256e+02  -1.30872700e+02
   -1.03175439e+03  -2.94238915e+02  -8.36753617e+02   4.77420371e+02
   -3.38091939e+02  -2.44272006e+02  -1.35130348e+02  -4.72973924e+02
   -6.19636207e+01  -7.37123284e+02  -4.28620473e+01   1.80929974e+02
    4.67912162e+02   2.22731582e+02   2.93578369e+02   1.34101279e+02
    9.04139841e+02  -3.91744880e+00  -2.88182153e+02  -1.22493089e+01
   -2.15621705e+02   1.59580065e+02  -9.57584381e+01  -6.41773592e+01
   -1.28168370e+02   9.42107498e+01   2.61332125e+01   7.00130475e+01
    8.58092989e+02  -2.62818439e+01   9.40455319e+01   2.82505159e+02]
 [ -4.70908104e+02  -8.29375323e+02  -9.93882131e+02  -1.47050049e+02
   -1.03443155e+03  -3.28570789e+02  -8.31014742e+02   4.92865993e+02
   -3.70050739e+02  -2.35488125e+02  -1.63833070e+02  -4.86930191e+02
   -9.74429858e+01  -7.48852374e+02  -6.17719584e+01   2.13942179e+02
    4.52542022e+02   2.83202323e+02   2.43990105e+02   1.72094231e+02
    9.65225890e+02  -2.92801036e+01  -3.13220814e+02  -4.60705452e+01
   -2.32787033e+02   1.38783264e+02  -6.23061347e+01  -1.05977672e+02
   -8.75333469e+01   1.31424380e+02  -1.99414766e+01   7.97712157e+01
    8.30620576e+02   9.19139268e+00   1.44727040e+02   2.65196706e+02]]
```

So, the values differ (though slightly) for every sample. I assume the model is doing *something*. I just dont know whats wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If class 2 is far more likely to occur than any of the other classes and the features are not informative enough to make strong distinctions between classes, then the model will always predict class 2.  Instead use
    svm.decision_function(X_pca)
to see the scores for each sample for each class.  If these are all the same, then something is wrong.  You could also look at
    svm.coef_
If all the coefficients are 0, then the model isn't doing anything.

And you didn't scale X_test.

Comment: I ensured the training is done equally for all samples so there is no bias for any class. I executed  {svm.decision_function(X_pca) } like you said and got slightly diffferent values . I'll add it to the question.

Comment: You forgot to scale X_test.

Comment: Fascinating! I scaled X_test and that fixed the problem. I honestly didn't think that would make much of a difference. But thank you!

Comment: Can you add "Remember to scale X_test" in your answer too?

Answer (score 0):

such problem mostly occurs when you are trying to scale train data but forgot to scale test data, in case of pipeline there is a major problem which is when you execute pipeline.fit() it actually fit the scaler too which means it will extract mean and std deviation based on train data, when you try to execute pipeline.predict() it just apply those extracted mean and std deviation on test data, if there is huge difference between test and train data, like the pattern is same but the difference is so huge that model failed to predict it accurately.